# Error initialising react hook with a function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why this code doesn't work:

```
let [kgFormValues, setKgFormValues] = useState<KgFormValues>(getKgFormValues());
```

Error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'kgFormValues' before initialization

But when removing the parentheses works:

```
let [kgFormValues, setKgFormValues] = useState<KgFormValues>(getKgFormValues);

function getKgFormValues() {
    return {
      ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Move function declaration before call it. getKgFormValues

Comment: Because you call a function before it's declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this to work, you must call the function *after* it's declared.

For example:

```
function getKgFormValues() {
    return {
      ...
    };
}

// now you can use it, as such:
let [kgFormValues, setKgFormValues] = useState<KgFormValues>(getKgFormValues);
```